# How to determine if glTF has animation data

Tags: animation, three.js, gltf

I've had a few errors progressing from displaying a static mesh,(works fine) to an animated one (mixed results). I suspect the fbx that I've been exporting to glTF is as fault, but I'd just like to ask:

Firstly, how do you determine if a glTF file has animation data/clips? And, if the model displaying doesn't have any animation will that cause any problems using calling the `AnimationMixer`?

This is what I have:

```
    // Mix and animate!
    mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( model );
    var clips = model.animations;

    // if there's no first animation; there's no animation
    if (mixer.clipAction( gltf.animations[ 0 ] ) == undefined)
    // if (clips == undefined) // doesn't seem to work
    {
        // console.log("-> clips " + clips);
        console.log("-> no anim for " + model.name);
    }
    else
    {
        mixer.clipAction( gltf.animations[ 0 ] ).play();
    }
```

only occasionally on a static mesh I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'uuid' of undefined` Which leaves be a little confused.

Answer (score 0):

The gltfloader calls the completion function with a structure.. in that struct is an .animations[] array. If that is empty, no animations were found. As long as you make your mixer and don't try to add an undefined animation, it should be fine by itself and you can add the animation later when you find one.